# Can not understand about vector function in C++ stl and differences

Tags: c++11, vector, stl

I am not able to figure out difference between `vector<set <int >> v(26)` and `vector<set < int > > v[26]`.  Please if possible explain how they work and how are they different with example.

Comment: Just try using them. You can't miss the differences once you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are invalid declarations. One is an illegal declaration of one `vector` with 26 elements and the other is an illegal declaration of an array of 26 `vector`s.

`set` is a class template and needs a *type* to be used.

Example:

```
vector<set<int>> v(26); // a vector with 26 sets of int
vector<set<int>> v[26]; // an array of 26 vectors of set of ints
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for wrong writing of question,my first question on stack overflow

Comment: @ramsingh You're welcome. No need to apologize. You wanted some clarification and I hope this helped.